# Boas práticas em modelagem de dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem

Sou estagiário e estou desenvolvendo uma pequena aplicação para auxiliar o pessoal da qualidade e desenvolvimento a cadastrar os casos de uso e etc, a aplicação é bem simples mesmo, ela é feita em angularJs com back-end C#, porém chegamos em um ponto da aplicação onde se faz necessário a validação destes casos de uso, eu como estagiário sugeri o seguinte banco:

[image: Modelagem simples]

Porém, quando ele me entregou a API ele juntou as tabelas em uma só.

Como sou estagiário e possuo um conhecimento pequeno, mas mesmo assim, ainda acho que juntar ambas tabelas em uma só não seja uma boa prática, gostaria da opnião da comunidade pra saber se dessa forma eu agrego o meu conhecimento em BD

Desde já, agradeço

Edit 1: Desculpe a falta de informações, tentei ser um pouco breve para poupar vosso tempo.

Possuo uma tela para **INICIAR** a validação de um caso de uso(Abaixo)[image: Tela]

Modelei a tabela daquela forma por quê preciso armazenar o início e o fim da ronda de validação da UC, caso o usuário saia antes de terminar de validar, ele pode continuar, então criei aquelas tabelas, assim teria um relacionamento simples para se trabalhar e requisições mais simples a API, porém a tabela que foi me entregue foi a seguinte

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao invés de duas tabelas, apenas uma tabela com auto referenciamento.

Não que isso seja um grande problema, me preocupo mais com a manutenção do banco e etc, apesar de ser um sistema pequeno, com pouco mais de 2000 mil registros.

Comment: Esquece boa prática, aprenda fazer. Só com essas informações ninguém consegue dizer se isto está correto ou não. Não sabemos o pra que serve `Teste`, pra que serve `Table`, o motivo de existir cada atributo, e não sabemos a relação entre esses dados.

Comment: o "Table" seria o caso de uso? Se sim e para cada de uso você vai ter vários testes, é melhor separar.

Comment: @Joe, é exatamente o que eu pensei, mas não recebi assim. E como não tenho muita experiência com isso, preferi perguntar para comunidade. Dá uma olhada, dei uma editada para edicionar mais informações

Comment: Achei algumas coisas estranhas na tabela unificada: id e testeId não seriam a mesma coisa? Quem é o flowId? Já na outra modelagem (que é mais sensata) senti falta da cardinalidade para entender melhor o que o @JoeTorres comentou sobre os vários testes. Um modelo mais completo com outras Classes ajudaria, pois vejo muitos Ids que levariam para outras classes (apesar que não se modela chaves em diagrama de classes) e não se deve usar o diagrama de classes para representar banco de dados.